# How to find out start and end day of the previous week

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

To find the start and end for the current week I managed to do this:

```
extension NSDate {
    static func week() -> (NSDate, NSDate) {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        calendar.firstWeekday = 2
        var interval = NSTimeInterval(0)
        var startOfWeek: NSDate?
        var endOfWeek: NSDate!
        calendar.rangeOfUnit(.WeekOfMonth, startDate: &startOfWeek, interval: &interval, forDate: NSDate())
        endOfWeek = startOfWeek?.dateByAddingTimeInterval(interval - 1)

        return (startOfWeek!, endOfWeek)
    }
}
```

How can I update this code to get the start/end of the previous week ?

Comment: Just call this function and subtract 7 days from each of the returned dates?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Getting first day of the previous week 
func getPreviousWeekStartDay() -> Date? {
    let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let sunday = gregorian.date(from: 
    gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))
    return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: sunday!)!
}

// Getting last day of previous week 
func getPreviousWeekEndDay() -> Date? {        
    let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))
    return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: sunday!)!
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can start counting from a week ago:

```
let weekInSeconds: Double = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
calendar.rangeOfUnit(.WeekOfMonth, startDate: &startOfWeek, interval: &interval, forDate: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -weekInSeconds))
```

You can now control which week (from now) you want to see, in the past of future, by using multiples of `weekInSeconds` (positive for future weeks, negative for past weeks, 0 for this week).

Comment: This is incorrect in all regions with daylight saving time, where a day can have 23, 24, or 25 hours.

Comment: Right - so you'd have to use NSTimeZone to find that out and fine-tune weekInSeconds inside the function.